# Issue from converting NSDistionary to Json in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

NSDictionary converting Bool value as 0 or 1 in Json
Is there a way to get value of Json property as true or false

Like { gender : true }, but not like { gender : 1 }

Comment: Please show the code you are using to do this conversion.

Comment: Thanks Every one for answering . I was Using Serialize class in which NSDictionary was being created. in that i i was checking like

Answer (score 2):

A 0 or 1 will be parsed as an `NSNumber` by `NSJSONSerialization`

You can acceess `boolValue` on `NSNumber`

here is some psuedo-swift

```
let number:NSNumber = dict['gender']

let boolValue = number.boolValue
```

Comment: His works for me. Here's a slightly tighter version:

let boolValue = dict["gender"] as NSNumber as Bool

Answer (score 0):

It isn't, at least using `NSJSONSerialization`. `BOOL`s are wrapped in `NSNumber`s (since `NSDictionary`s require objects), which serialize as numbers, rather than `true` or `false`. `NSNumber`s don't know what type of number (int, float, BOOL, etc.) they store, so `NSJSONSerialization` can't know how to serialize them. Most JSON libraries understand this though, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Every one for answering . I was Using Serialize class in which NSDictionary was being created. in that i i was checking like property is Bool and also property is Int. in this case bool is converted to Int1 so i was unable to fine value is Bool or Int.

> /*
>
> Converts A class to a dictionary, used for serializing dictionaries to
>   JSON
>
> Supported objects:
>   - Serializable derived classes
>   - Arrays of Serializable
>   - NSData
>   - String, Numeric, and all other NSJSONSerialization supported objects
>   - https://gist.github.com/turowicz/e7746a9c035356f9483d
>   */

Class look like this.

```
class Serializable : NSObject{

    func toDictionary() -> NSDictionary {
        var aClass : AnyClass? = self.dynamicType
        var propertiesCount : CUnsignedInt = 0
        let propertiesInAClass : UnsafeMutablePointer<objc_property_t> = class_copyPropertyList(aClass, &propertiesCount)
        var propertiesDictionary : NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()

        for var i = 0; i < Int(propertiesCount); i++ {
            var property = propertiesInAClass[i]
            var propName = NSString(CString: property_getName(property), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            var propType = property_getAttributes(property)
            var propValue : AnyObject! = self.valueForKey(propName!);

            if(propName == "isActivator")
            {
                println("")
            }

            if propValue is Serializable {
                propertiesDictionary.setValue((propValue as Serializable).toDictionary(), forKey: propName!)
            } else if propValue is Array<Serializable> {
                var subArray = Array<NSDictionary>()
                for item in (propValue as Array<Serializable>) {
                    subArray.append(item.toDictionary())
                }
                propertiesDictionary.setValue(subArray, forKey: propName!)
            } else if propValue is NSData {
                 propertiesDictionary.setValue((propValue as NSData).base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil), forKey: propName!)
                 } else if propValue is Int {
                 propertiesDictionary.setValue((propValue as Int), forKey: propName!)
                 } else if propValue is Float {
                 propertiesDictionary.setValue((propValue as Float), forKey: propName!)
                 } else if propValue is Double {
                 propertiesDictionary.setValue((propValue as Double), forKey: propName!)
                 } else if propValue is String {
                 propertiesDictionary.setValue((propValue as String), forKey: propName!)

            } else if propValue is BoolJ {
                propertiesDictionary.setValue((propValue as BoolJ).value, forKey: propName!)
            } else if propValue is NSDate {
                var date = propValue as NSDate
                let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "Z"
                var dateString = NSString(format: "/Date(%.0f000%@)/", date.timeIntervalSince1970, dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date))
                propertiesDictionary.setValue(dateString, forKey: propName!)
            } else if propValue is NSNumber {
                propertiesDictionary.setValue((propValue as Float), forKey: propName!)
                       } else {
                propertiesDictionary.setValue(propValue, forKey: propName!)
            }
        }

        return propertiesDictionary
    }

    func toJson() -> NSData! {
        var dictionary = self.toDictionary()
        var err: NSError?
        return NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dictionary, options:NSJSONWritingOptions(0), error: &err)
    }

    func toJsonString() -> NSString! {
        return NSString(data: self.toJson(), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    }

    override init() { }
}
```

so what i did is i created my own Bool class and inherited NSObject

```
class BoolJ : NSObject {
    var value:Bool=false
    init(value:Bool)
    {
        self.value=value
    }
}
```

now i can check that property is BoolJ in that case i can store what ever value that i want.